# extract a subset of a data frame where records are separated by a specific time period

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, datediff

(I have modified this question to make it more explicit.)

I have a dataset as follows:

`data <- structure(list(id = 1:12, personID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), lastName = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("james", "joan", 
"lucy", "mary"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(5L, 5L, 
8L, 9L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 10L), .Label = c("1/01/2012", 
"10/04/2011", "11/01/2012", "11/08/2011", "12/01/2012", "12/04/2012", 
"12/12/2011", "14/01/2012", "16/01/2012", "24/06/2010", "24/06/2011"
), class = "factor"), status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "personID", "lastName", 
"date", "status"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L
))`

I need to extract a subset from the data frame to include records where each row occured more than once in a period of greater than 8 weeks.

The extraction needs to search from the oldest record and then select the next (more recent) additional record for the same personID that was greater then 8 weeks since the previous record. Upon finding another record older then 8 weeks it should repeat the process using what the more recent second record as the new starting point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
maxDiff <- tapply(data$date,data$personID,function(x) max(dist(x)))
subset(data,personID %in% names(maxDiff[maxDiff>(8*7)]))
  id personID lastName       date status
1  1        1    james 2012-01-12      1
4  4        4     mary 2012-01-16      1
5  5        4     mary 2012-04-12      1
8  8        1    james 2011-06-24      1
```

Comment: This would pick out the most-separated pair of records for each person, provided the separation exceeds 8 weeks. However if a person has records on day 1, day 90, day 200, then the OP may want all *three* records for that person. This needs to be clarified by @John.

Comment: @PrasadChalasani Good point, I'll think about it some more. `expand.grid` is probably needed.

Comment: that sounds promising -- so, look at  `dist` entries `(i,j)` bigger than 56, and find a (maximal-length?) sequence of these...

Comment: For example if a given person has records on days `(1,30,60,90,120,150)`, then either the sequence `(1,60,120)` or the sequence `(30,90,150)` would qualify.

Comment: @PrasadChalasani and @James, this is harder than I first thought and I did not explain very well at first . I need to return cases for each person only if there was an 8 week separation between subsequent periods. Therefore if there were records for a person at `(1,30,60,90,120 and 150)` I would only want `(1,60)` and `(90,120)`. Think of it like this - The first set `(1,60)` is two events separated by a period > 8 weeks. The `60` is the end of that event so now I wish to find previous events in periods of time separated by > 8 weeks (without duplicating the event recorded at 60 in `(1,60)`.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, though I'm sure someone else can give you a better answer.

```
require(plyr)

diffWeek <- function (df) { 
  abs(df$date[1] - df$date[2])}

eightWeeks <- 7*8 # 56 days
aux.data <- ddply(data, "lastName", function (df) diffWeek(df) >   eightWeeks)

data[data$lastName %in% aux.data[aux.data[,2]==T,1],] # this willreturn the data.frame.
```

Note that my answer doesn't generalize well. If I have more time I'll try to generalize it. But it should work for now.